# Rake DB not working with Paperclip (ruby 2.4.0p0 and Rails 5.1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Paperclip to create a Pinterest clone, and I'm trying to rake my migration file but I got an error:

I was able to run the generate cmd:

```
pinterested-app git:(master) ✗ rails generate paperclip user image
Running via Spring preloader in process 88926
      create  db/migrate/20170511010912_add_attachment_image_to_users.rb
```

But when I ran tried to rake the db I got the following:

```
➜  pinterested-app git:(master) ✗ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class AddAttachmentImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:525:in `inherited'
/Users/rthomas/Dropbox/rails-dev/pinterested-app/db/migrate/20170511010912_add_attachment_image_to_users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:962:in `load_migration'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:958:in `migration'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `disable_ddl_transaction'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1305:in `use_transaction?'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1297:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1229:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1201:in `block in migrate_without_lock'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `each'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1200:in `migrate_without_lock'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1150:in `migrate'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rthomas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rails is asking to specify the Rails release and you're using rails 5.1, try to add [5.1] in the end of ActiveRecord::Migration in your migration file:

```
class AddAttachmentImageToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

Then try to run again.

Comment: If you have to migrate an app that already is being used in production, can you just update the migration with the version as you said? since those are gonna be migrations that already exists on the production server, is rails gonna run it again?